# Having trouble translating sentences into propositional logic

Tags: propositional-calculus, logic-translation

Translate the following sentences above into propositional logic, using the scheme below.

B = Bones is a hothead

K = Kirk is a hothead

S = Spock is a hothead

U = Uhuru is a hothead

1. Neither Uhuru nor Spock is a hothead.
2. Both Kirk and Bones are hotheads, but Spock isn’t, and neither is Uhuru.
3. Either Kirk or Bones is a hothead, but not both.

Answer (score 0):

1.$$\overline U  \wedge \overline S.$$
2. $$K\wedge B \wedge \overline S \wedge \overline U.$$
3. $$K \lor B \land \overline {K\land B}.$$